# Say you had a Rubik's cube in a certain starting state and chose moves randomly and uniformly. How long on average would it take to solve it?

Tags: probability, random-walk, rubiks-cube

So say you have a Rubik's cube in a certain state (you can make your own assumptions about what state, I'm guessing the majority of states give about the same answer) and you alter it by randomly and uniformly choosing moves, one after another. Here a move is defined as rotation of a face of the cube either 1, 2, or 3 times (you can't leave the cube the way it is). How many moves on average would it take to solve it? Also, how would you generalize this problem, or what are some general techniques to handle it?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608168/random-solving-of-a-rubik-cube

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate of the stated question: there you _start_ in a solved state and want to get _back_ to a solved state by random moves. Here, starting from a not-necessarily-solved state, things seem to get more complex than that -- at least the argument that carries the day in the other question won't work here without some adjustment.