# The expected number of steps for a knight to move from the lower left to the upper right corner of the chess board

Tags: combinatorics, markov-chains, expected-value

What is the expected number of steps for a knight at each step executing a legal move with uniform probability to move from the lower-left corner to the upper-right corner of the chessboard? Of course one can solve a big system of (some $36$ or so) linear equations, but I suppose there is some trick making use of some symmetry. Perhaps it is related to [this question on the expected return time for the knight on a chessboard corner](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1588958/64809).

Comment: You are assuming that at each stage the knight picks randomly from the available moves?

Comment: @almagest: Yes. I have now edited the question to explicitly state this premise.

Comment: I would try the matrix approach first...

Comment: This question was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473589) and then deleted by the post author after someone indicated that it was part of the GSA SPARK Coding Competition. I couldn't find any public information on this competition and its end date. Please consult the [contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774) and defer this question in case it refers to an ongoing contest. (I'm also flagging the question for moderator attention.) By the way, I find the question very interesting and intend to answer it as appropriate.

Comment: @joriki: I see. I did not know it was a contest problem. I saw it on Art of Problem Solving. Are you suggesting that I delete the question for now?

Comment: @Hans: That's what I would have suggested if you'd found it as part of an ongoing contest. Since you didn't and the contest mentioned by the other user isn't public, we have no way of knowing whether the problem is actually part of that contest and whether that contest is still ongoing. My view would be that in these circumstances we can leave the question open unless we get more specific information about the contest. But I've flagged this for the attention of the moderators and they can decide whether to temporarily delete it or leave it open for now.

Comment: I'd suggest that you link to the source at the Art of Problem Solving, though.